# Better way to overide content page in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am creating custom content pages using this function in my template file

```
function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$var, $hook) {
  if (isset($var['node']->type)) {
    $var['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $var['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Then I am creating a custom page--"content_name".tpl.php file for my content. However this also overrides the edit, moderate, track pages for that content as well. I only want it to override the main content page. Is there an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to be something like:

```
function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$var, $hook) {
  if (isset($var['node']->type) && is_null(arg(2))) { // the edited line
    $var['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $var['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad that's exactly what I was after.